# Old Programmer looking to use subversion assembla

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

Please help… Old Programmer looking to use subversion assembla at my firm. I am doing alot of Java in Eclipse and my issues is the following. I am going to make it very easy.

1) I build a web site in Eclipse with JSP. I check it in and commit. it is live

2) I start working on version two of the site but someone finds a bug in one of the prod JSPs. how do I checkout that version of the jsp update it and then commit it to the project. please tell me the right steps

Comment: `svn co`, i would think? maybe you clarify a bit what you're asking after?

Comment: if you use eclipse you may want to install [subclipse](Which programming language are you using?) (SVN plug-in for eclipse): that should make your life easier, because you can import your project into SVN, check-out and commit files with a right-mouse click.

Comment: If you are live on commit, I'm hoping that you have some sort of automated checkout and deployment process onto a different "production" machine.  If not, you're playing on the razor's edge, and eventually you'll be cut.

Comment: just for info, on decentralized VCSes, a very cool "trick" is to "go back" to the first revision where the bug was introduced and fix the bug there, then merge upstream. You simply do a new prod build from where you made the last prod release (by "going forward" to your last prod release). You then resume to where you where (working on your version 2.0) by doing an upstream merge.  It's an oversimplification but the concept is very cool: you "go back", fix, and merge upstream, instead of fixing, making a patch and patching downstream. It's called a *"daggy fix"* and it rocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the workflow that most organizations use:

- When you make a production release, you tag it. In SVN, this is done with `svn cp`, copying `trunk` into a named directory under `tags`.
- If you need to make bugfixes to a production release, you use `svn cp` to copy the tagged revision into a branch under `branches`. You then check out this named revision, make your changes, and check in.
- If you're going to push the changes out to production, you can tag them from the branch, again using `svn cp`. Tags are cheap in Subversion.
- If the fixes you made in the branch need to go back into `trunk`, you can merge them.

This is covered in the [docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.html) (this is a link to the chapter on branching and merging, but I recommend you read the introductory material if you're not familiar with SVN).

Answer (score 2):

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/index.html

Read chapters 2 and 3 and that will be enough to hit the ground running.  The command you are likely looking for is `svn update -rNNN` however, without some background on SVN odds are excellent that you'll misuse it as SVN is very like (yet in some ways different) than the old school CVS, RCS, SCCS like systems.

You might want to skim chapter 1 too, as the revisioning model SVN uses is a little different than tight locking models (if you've been using one of those).